# Securing Webapi when it is not to be consumed by browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

My Webapi has certain methods which would be invoked by clients - which are not web browsers, but native applications on client's server.

1.Should I be using SSL + OAuth2.0 for securing the webapi?
2.What are the disadvantages of using SSL and a simple SHA hash token mechanism?
2.If so, is it better to add IP address of the clients as an extra parameter?
3.Should it be a part of the header or body of request?

Also, I didn't come across good documentation of the OAuth2.0 C# server implementations, can someone point them?